# USBc 2.0 vs USBc 3.x alternate mode

Tags: tablet, hdmi, displays, display-port, usb-c

Hi all I have the following question:

I want a tablet for presentations on external monitors.

Does the tablet need USBc 2 or higher USBc 3.x to make an adapter cable work from the tablets USBc to an external monitor HDMI?

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, USB type C needs to be used in displayport or thunderbolt mode to sopport external displays (HDMI, VGA, DP, doesnt matter). USB 3.x wont be able to run a display except if it also supports displayport. What I do know for sure is that iPads support AirPlay, where you can wirelessly stream a video signal. I think there are also dongles that convert AirPlay to HDMI on the tv side.